# I am getting a returned a non-zero code: 8 when building my docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

I am setting up Kafka and zookeeper through docker; however, my whenever I build my image I keep getting a code 8 error when it gets to:

```
wget -q  https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.asc .
```

I have tried to change the file format in the download-kafka.sh to unix already.

### Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM Wurstmeister/base

MAINTAINER Wurstmeister

ENV ZOOKEEPER_VERSION 3.4.13

#Download Zookeeper
RUN wget -q http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/KEYS && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.asc && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.md5

#Verify download
RUN md5sum -c zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.md5 && \
gpg --import KEYS && \
gpg --verify zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.asc

#Install
RUN tar -xzf zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz -C /opt

#Configure
RUN mv /opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/conf/zoo_sample.cfg /opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/conf/zoo.cfg

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
ENV ZK_HOME /opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}
RUN sed  -i "s|/tmp/zookeeper|$ZK_HOME/data|g" $ZK_HOME/conf/zoo.cfg; mkdir $ZK_HOME/data

ADD start-zk.sh /usr/bin/start-zk.sh 
EXPOSE 2181 2888 3888

WORKDIR /opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}
VOLUME ["/opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/conf", "/opt/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/data"]

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd && bash /usr/bin/start-zk.sh
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to this link, then `3.4.13` doesn't exist anymore

https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/

You can change to `ENV ZOOKEEPER_VERSION 3.4.14`, or just use an existing Zookeeper Docker image